# Jquery load() inside Datatable

Tags: jquery, load, datatables

I can't figure out why my load function is not getting fired with the following snippet. Till jqueries load everything works I can log datas what I passed to my function

```
   <script>
    var oTable;
    /* Formating function for row details */
    function fnFormatDetails(nTr)
    {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        $(nTr).fadeOut();
        console.log(aData[1]);
        container_id = aData[1];
        var sOut = '<div id="edit_prod_settings_' + aData[1] + '"></div>';

        return sOut;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        oTable = $('#feed_products').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "../admin/?controller=products&action=getTable",
            "aoColumns": [
                {"sClass": "center", "bSortable": false},
                null,
                {sWidth: '20%'},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {"sClass": "center", "bSortable": false},
                {"sClass": "center", "bSortable": false, sWidth: '5%'},
                {"sClass": "center", "bSortable": false}
            ],
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']],
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings)
            {
                $('button.edit').on('click', function() {

                    var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                    if (oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr))
                    {
                        /* This row is already open - close it */
                        this.src = "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs edit'><i class='icon-plus'></i></button>";
                        oTable.fnClose(nTr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Open this row */

                        this.src = "<button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs edit'><i class='icon-minus'></i></button>";
                        //oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details');
                        var openedRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details');
                        console.log(openedRow);
                        $(openedRow).each(function() {
                            console.log(container_id);                        
                            $('#edit_prod_settings_'+ container_id).load('../admin/?controller=products&action=getProdDetails&prod_id=' + container_id);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Logging

```
console.log(aData[1]);
        console.log('#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1]);
        console.log('../admin/?controller=products&   action=getProdDetails&prod_id=' + aData[1]);
```

Response

```
1402879831
#edit_prod_settings_1402879831
```

the last one is not returning any value

Comment: Is the problem about the click event not getting triggered when '.edit' is clicked?

Comment: no click works, console.log(aData[1]); returns data

Comment: so when you mean load function, which function is not getting fired? Can you specify the function name.

Comment: thanks for feedback fnFormatDetails(nTr) look comment behind console.log

Comment: Can you call the function explicitly inside "$(document).ready". You can specify it at the last.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can not call function inside of "$(document).ready" but anyway I was trying it and is the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39443/discussion-between-fefe-and-vivek)

Comment: please post a fiddle which will reproduce that error. There is too much code that is used by you, but you haven't pasted it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element that you call `load()` on doesn't exist.

From your comment "`console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1]).length );` returns 0" I think thats the case.

This is because you call `load()` before your element is appended to HTML:

- you call `oTable.fnOpen` with `fnFormatDetails(nTr)` as one of parameters
- in `fnFormatDetails` you return call `load()` on element with id `containerId`, **which doesn't yet exist**
- then you return `sOut`, which is the HTML code for the element with id `containerId`
- after `fnFormatDetails` returns, `oTable.fnOpen` actually executes, appending contents of `sOut` to your HTML. **From now the element with id `#edit_prod_settings_"+aData[1]` exists.** (and will exist until you call `fnClose`)

I'd suggest calling `load()` **after** fnOpen executes to fix your issue. As `fnOpen` returns table element, this is pretty simple:

```
var openedRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details');
$(openedRow).each(function () {
    // here goes the function that you want called after fnOpen 
    // in your case, .load()
});
```

Hovewer, you'll need to restructure your code a bit to have `aData[1]` value accessible from outside of `fnFormatDetails`.

Comment: This is already debugged with firebug xhr the load function is not getting fired

Comment: What does `'#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1]` evaluate to? Do you have this element on page?

Comment: let me make an example on jsfiddle

Comment: thank you for your feedback as you said '#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1] returns null. The problem that div I create on the flow which is var sOut = '<div id="edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1] + '"></div>'; How to make this one in the propper way?

Comment: please include in your question the code that you use to put this div on your page  (probably `oTable.fnOpen`).

Comment: you call `load()` before appending element. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for all of the feedbacks. Sorry for the late reply. It seems to work now. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load) :

> If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the document does not contain an element with id="result" — the Ajax request will *not* be sent.

What does your selector return ?

```
console.log( '#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1] );
console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1]) );
console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+ aData[1]).length );
```

[edit]

> console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1]).length ); returns 0

This means that, when you call the `$('#edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1])` selector, there is no node with id `'edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1]` in your page.

Either fix your selector, or create the node you need before calling `.load()`.

Or load the content using `$.ajax( ... )`, and explicitly add the html in the `success` callback.

Comment: here is what I get when I log I've been extending my comment

Comment: @fefe: and what does `console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1]).length );` print ?

Comment: console.log( $('#edit_prod_settings_'+aData[1]).length ); returns 0